# Install apk on emulator not from playstore

Tags: android, google-play, apk, reverse-engineering

I downloaded an app from Raccon. I got some files:

```
com.company.name-3423.apk
config.ar-3423.apk
config.armeabi_v7a-3423.apk
config.en-3423.apk
config.iw-3423.apk
config.ru-3423.apk
config.xhdpi-3423.apk
```

I dragged the com.company.name-3423.apk file to the emulator and then tried to open the installed app but it kept crashing.
If I download from the Play Store it works OK.

- What are these files?
- How should I install it on the emulator?

Comment: looks like these arent standalone APKs, but parts took from [AAB](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) file

Comment: @snachmsm Is there a way I can create the AAB file from these?

Comment: don't have idea, but you can inspect [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool), which extracts "full" APK from AAB. maybe there is a way to point few APKs intead of whole AAB